# C++0x: thread, gcc or my error?

Tags: multithreading, c++11, gcc4

**Is it GCC 4.7.0** or is it me? What do I do wrong?

This throws an `std::system_error` *"operation not permitted"* exception:

```cpp
struct DumbFib {
    size_t operator()(size_t n) { return fib(n); }
    static size_t fib(size_t n) {
        return n<2 ? 1 : fib(n-2)+fib(n-1);
    }
};

void sample() {
    DumbFib dumbfib;
    thread th{ dumbfib, 35 };    // <- system_error!
    th.join();
};
```

while this works:

```cpp
void work(size_t loop) {
    for(int l = loop; l>0; --l) {
        for(int i = 1000*1000; i>0; --i)
            ;
        cerr << l << "...";
    }
    cerr << endl;
}

int main() {
    //sample();
    thread t { work, 100 };     // <- fine
    t.join();
}
```

The difference is, of course:

- The not-working code uses a **Functor** (class with `operator()`)
- The working code uses a function-pointer.

**Do I use the *functor* wrong, somewhere?** I can not see where, do you? Is it a hint that the `gdb` has this in its stack:

```
#7  ... in std::thread::_M_start_thread (..., __b=warning: RTTI symbol not found\
  for class 'std::_Sp_counted_ptr_inplace<std::thread::_Impl<std::\
  _Bind_simple<DumbFib()(int)> >, ..., (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2>
```

Notes: I also tried

- Initialize `DumbFib` first, giving it a member-variable `n_=35`, same result.
- Giving the functor directly with `thread th{ DumbFib, 35 };` or `thread th{ DumbFib{}, 35 };`

Comment: What system are you running this on?

Comment: linux 64bit (ubuntu 10.4 LTS), gcc-4.7.0, svn checkout from last week.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

When compiling your code with `g++`, use the `-pthread` option.

Comment: How embarrassing .. I had that error once and thought I corrected it. I didn't. So, now it works! Great!

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing similar problem, and thanks Jason, it solved my problem

The exact options will be

```
g++ code.cpp -lpthread -std=c++0x
```

That's what I have to do on *g++ version 4.6.3*