# "Operation not permitted" when trying to execute compiled c++

Tags: c++, websocket, g++, execution, permission-denied

I've compiled this [websocket++ print server example](http://www.zaphoyd.com/websocketpp/manual/building-program-websocket), executed it, and confirmed it worked by testing on my server and a browser.

Now, I've compiled this [websocket++ broadcast server example](https://github.com/zaphoyd/websocketpp/blob/experimental/examples/broadcast_server/broadcast_server.cpp) with the command `g++ -O3 -o bServer broadcast_server.cpp -I ~/websocketpp-experimental/ -std=c++0x -D_WEBSOCKETPP_CPP11_STL_ -D_WEBSOCKETPP_NO_CPP11_REGEX_ -lboost_regex -lboost_system` according to the [author's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1047661/zaphoyd) [recommendations](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15469310/1382306).

`./bServer` gives `Operation not permitted`.

`ls -l bServer` gives `-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 574151 Jun 29 22:31 bServer` which as far as I know indicates that it's permitted to be executed.

How can I execute this program?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

brian got to the heart of the matter, and here's the total solution:

In the broadcast_server.cpp example, there's

```
        try {
            m_server.run();
        } catch (const std::exception & e) {
            std::cout << e.what() << std::endl;
        } catch (websocketpp::lib::error_code e) {
            std::cout << e.message() << std::endl;
        } catch (...) {
            std::cout << "other exception" << std::endl;
        }
```

Googling `std "Operation not permitted"` autocompletes to `std thread operation not permitted`, and the first result is this question: [C++0x: thread, gcc or my error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7359575/c0x-thread-gcc-or-my-error)

Using the `-pthread` flag fixes it.

Answer (score 2):

Your program is printing this message.  Find where it is printed and print more information.